# Using AngularJS template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on a big project using springboot framework and AngularJS, I am new to angularJS, I've just started learning it for not more than 4 days, I'm trying to use an AngularJS template in order to make my work easier, I chose a template that contains most of the functions that I need in my project, but the problem is that the structure and the syntaxes are so diffrent of what I've seen in angularJS and I don't know which version of angular it is, knowing that I don't have documentation of this template, here's an example of how the code of most of the files looks like and the structure too, can you guys help me to know which angular version is?? [template hierarchy 1][template hierarchy2] `

```js
define(['layout/module', 'lodash', 'notification'], function (module, _) {

    'use strict';

    module.registerDirective('demoStates', function ($rootScope) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            templateUrl: 'app/layout/directives/demo/demo-states.tpl.html',
            scope: true,
            link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
                element.parent().css({
                    position: 'relative'
                });

                element.on('click', '#demo-setting', function () {
                    element.toggleClass('activate')
                })
            },
            controller: function ($scope) {
                var $root = $('body');

                $scope.$watch('fixedHeader', function (fixedHeader) {
                    localStorage.setItem('sm-fixed-header', fixedHeader);
                    $root.toggleClass('fixed-header', fixedHeader);
                    if (fixedHeader == false) {
                        $scope.fixedRibbon = false;
                        $scope.fixedNavigation = false;
                    }
                });


                $scope.$watch('fixedNavigation', function (fixedNavigation) {
                    localStorage.setItem('sm-fixed-navigation', fixedNavigation);
                    $root.toggleClass('fixed-navigation', fixedNavigation);
                    if (fixedNavigation) {
                        $scope.insideContainer = false;
                        $scope.fixedHeader = true;
                    } else {
                        $scope.fixedRibbon = false;
                    }
                });


                $scope.$watch('fixedRibbon', function (fixedRibbon) {
                    localStorage.setItem('sm-fixed-ribbon', fixedRibbon);
                    $root.toggleClass('fixed-ribbon', fixedRibbon);
                    if (fixedRibbon) {
                        $scope.fixedHeader = true;
                        $scope.fixedNavigation = true;
                        $scope.insideContainer = false;
                    }
                });

                $scope.$watch('fixedPageFooter', function (fixedPageFooter) {
                    localStorage.setItem('sm-fixed-page-footer', fixedPageFooter);
                    $root.toggleClass('fixed-page-footer', fixedPageFooter);
                });

                $scope.$watch('insideContainer', function (insideContainer) {
                    localStorage.setItem('sm-inside-container', insideContainer);
                    $root.toggleClass('container', insideContainer);
                    if (insideContainer) {
                        $scope.fixedRibbon = false;
                        $scope.fixedNavigation = false;
                    }
                });

                $scope.$watch('rtl', function (rtl) {
                    localStorage.setItem('sm-rtl', rtl);
                    $root.toggleClass('smart-rtl', rtl);
                });

                $scope.$watch('menuOnTop', function (menuOnTop) {
                    $rootScope.$broadcast('$smartLayoutMenuOnTop', menuOnTop);
                    localStorage.setItem('sm-menu-on-top', menuOnTop);
                    $root.toggleClass('menu-on-top', menuOnTop);

                    if(menuOnTop)$root.removeClass('minified');
                });

                $scope.$watch('colorblindFriendly', function (colorblindFriendly) {
                    localStorage.setItem('sm-colorblind-friendly', colorblindFriendly);
                    $root.toggleClass('colorblind-friendly', colorblindFriendly);
                });


                $scope.fixedHeader = localStorage.getItem('sm-fixed-header') == 'true';
                $scope.fixedNavigation = localStorage.getItem('sm-fixed-navigation') == 'true';
                $scope.fixedRibbon = localStorage.getItem('sm-fixed-ribbon') == 'true';
                $scope.fixedPageFooter = localStorage.getItem('sm-fixed-page-footer') == 'true';
                $scope.insideContainer = localStorage.getItem('sm-inside-container') == 'true';
                $scope.rtl = localStorage.getItem('sm-rtl') == 'true';
                $scope.menuOnTop = localStorage.getItem('sm-menu-on-top') == 'true' || $root.hasClass('menu-on-top');
                $scope.colorblindFriendly = localStorage.getItem('sm-colorblind-friendly') == 'true';


                $scope.skins = appConfig.skins;

                $scope.smartSkin = localStorage.getItem('sm-skin') || appConfig.smartSkin;


                $scope.setSkin = function (skin) {
                    $scope.smartSkin = skin.name;
                    $root.removeClass(_.pluck($scope.skins, 'name').join(' '));
                    $root.addClass(skin.name);
                    localStorage.setItem('sm-skin', skin.name);
                    $("#logo img").attr('src', skin.logo);
                };


                if($scope.smartSkin != "smart-style-0"){
                    $scope.setSkin(_.find($scope.skins, {name: $scope.smartSkin}))
                }


                $scope.factoryReset = function () {
                    $.SmartMessageBox({
                        title: "<i class='fa fa-refresh' style='color:green'></i> Clear Local Storage",
                        content: "Would you like to RESET all your saved widgets and clear LocalStorage?1",
                        buttons: '[No][Yes]'
                    }, function (ButtonPressed) {
                        if (ButtonPressed == "Yes" && localStorage) {
                            localStorage.clear();
                            location.reload()
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

`[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqzOM.png)

Comment: From the [`java` tag description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info): "*Java (**not to be confused with JavaScript or JScript or JS**) [...]*". From the [`javascript` tag description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info): "*JavaScript (**not to be confused with Java**) [...]*"

Comment: Yes, i already know, thank you, i mentioned the java tag in here because  i want to integrate this template with a java EE project

Comment: This is AngularJS 1.x.  If you're just getting started with Angular I would suggest starting with the latest version rather than one that is several years old.  Start here: https://angular.io/

Comment: This code is wrapped in require.js(http://requirejs.org/) which is a JavaScript module loader. That's why it looks different than typical AngularJS. It's not possible to tell you the version of Angular JS that is running without looking at the script tag that loads the library. Also, `registerDirective` is not a standard AngularJS function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so where can i find the script tag that loads the library?

Comment: All the Html files that i have in this template are written by a normal and simple html code, it doesnt contain any javascript code